# Is there a non toxic moisture indicator that can be applied on a wall?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

I am looking for a substance that could serve as an indicator for a risk of mold growth, e.g. by a change of its hue. Cobalt chloride is both irritant and carcinogenic so is not an option. I've found this [indicator](http://ftp.mn-net.com/english/Flyer_Catalogs/Test_Sticks_Test_Papers/PI_non_toxic_humidity_indicatorEN.PDF) but its threshold (8%) is not relevant for mold growth on a concrete and plaster wall which I guess is probably around 15-20% (I've found [data](https://www.aecb.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Fact-Sheet-Moisture-Requirements-for-Mold-Growth-via-E-Rirsch.pdf) only for wood where the threshold is 16%).